# Getting error in my console while trying to implement Angular-Cache (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a ionic project and I am trying to implement caching with [Angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache). Implemented angular-cache and now when I run it I get an error coming from my controller but I don't see any fault in my controller code.

[image]

Part of my app.js code:

```
angular.module('Chemicar', ['ionic','ChemicarProduct.controllers', 'ChemicarProduct.services', 'angular-cache'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, CacheFactory) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    CacheFactory("productsCache", { storageMode: "localStorage", maxAge: 5000, deletionOnExpire: "aggressive"});

  });
})
```

My service.js code:

```
angular.module('ChemicarProduct.services', [])

.service('ChemicarProductService', function($http, $q, CacheFactory){

    var url1 = "XXXXXXXXX";    
    var productsCache = CacheFactory.get('productsCache');

    var self = {
        'products' : [],
        'loadProducts' : function(){    
            var d = $q.defer(),
                cacheKey = "products",
                productsData = productsCache.get(cacheKey);

            if(productsData){
                console.log("Found data inside cache" , productsCache);
                d.resolve(productsCache);
            }
            else{
                $http.get(url1)
                .success(function(data){
                    self.products = data;
                    console.log("Received data via http " , self.products);
                    productsCache.put(cacheKey, self.products);
                    d.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(msg){
                    console.log("Error while making http call " , msg);
                    d.reject("The promise was not fulfilled", data);
                });
                return d.promise;
            }     
        }
    };
    return self;
});
```

My controller.js code:

```
angular.module('ChemicarProduct.controllers', ['ChemicarProduct.services'])

.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, ChemicarProductService, $ionicLoading){

    $scope.productItems = [];
    $ionicLoading.show({template: "Loading..."});

    ChemicarProductService.loadProducts().then(function success(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.productsItems = ChemicarProductService.products;
        console.log('&&&&&&&&' , $scope.productItems);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    },
    function error (data){
        console.log(data)
    });   

})
```

Comment: also post error trace not as image but as text,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In service you call `return d.promise;` only when `if(productsData){}` returns `false`.

This is a reason why `ChemicarProductService.loadProducts()` doesn't return promise aka:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Change to:

```
.service('ChemicarProductService', function($http, $q, CacheFactory){

    var url1 = "XXXXXXXXX";    
    var productsCache = CacheFactory.get('productsCache');

    var self = {
        'products' : [],
        'loadProducts' : function(){    
            var d = $q.defer(),
                cacheKey = "products",
                productsData = productsCache.get(cacheKey);

            if(productsData){
                console.log("Found data inside cache" , productsCache);
                d.resolve(productsCache);
            }
            else{
                $http.get(url1)
                .success(function(data){
                    self.products = data;
                    console.log("Received data via http " , self.products);
                    productsCache.put(cacheKey, self.products);
                    d.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(msg){
                    console.log("Error while making http call " , msg);
                    d.reject("The promise was not fulfilled", data);
                });
                //return d.promise;
            }

           return d.promise;      // <---- fix
        }
    };
    return self;
});
```